# UWP keep light on

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-phone, led, flashlight

I was playing around with the Flash and the camera API in UWP c#. Everything is working fine (see the code snippets below). However I was wondering on how to keep the Flashlight on, when turning off the screen on the phone.

Because as soon, as I press the power button on the right side of my phone, the flash turns off automatically and does not turn on, when I unlock the device again. I want the Flashlight to be active even, when the screen is turned off.

```
var cameraID = await GetCameraDeviceInfoAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
if (cameraID != null)
{
   this.captureManager = new MediaCapture();

   var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
   settings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video;
   settings.PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview;
   settings.AudioDeviceId = string.Empty;
   settings.VideoDeviceId = cameraID.Id;

   await this.captureManager.InitializeAsync(settings);

   this.mediaPreview = new CaptureElement();
   this.mediaPreview.Source = this.captureManager;
   await this.captureManager.StartPreviewAsync();
}

var flash = this.captureManager.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl;
flash.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know is there any way for windows phone to keep the flashlight on from C#.
But you can keep alive the app when phone screen is look by the following code. So your flashlight will be also alive.

for UWP

```
Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest KeepScreenOnRequest = new Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest();
KeepScreenOnRequest.RequestActive();
```

for WP

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

Comment: I was wondering, how those torch apps are doing it. I was trying one from the store and when turning off the screen or navigating away from the app, it continued being on. So I thought, there must be a trick somewhere.

Comment: I'm still searching for the solution. I will post a solution as soon, as I can find it. But so far no luck